# Javascript Hide URL in a mailto with text

Tags: javascript, string, url

I have create a "mailto" that opens a window with mail, and body. I want in the body of that mail to show a text, which when you click on, it redirects you to a link. Is it possible, since there's no DOM, so no `id` or `tag` to grab?

I tried to put this:

```
 var str = "Free Web Building Tutorials!";
 var result = str.link("https://www.w3schools.com");
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work _how_? What happens? What are you doing with `result`? Please see how to write a [mcve] and [ask]. It sounds like you want to execute JavaScript in an HTML email to create a link element? Why not just hard-code the HTML for it?

Answer (score 0):

You may not put a JavaScript in mail body, all mail clients generally strip-off scripts for security reasons.

If its just a text and a link, make the email body as `Html` and then just add

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Free Web Building Tutorials!</a>
```

Any other html stuff will also work.

===== Edit =====

Based on your comment, you should try like this:

```
mailto:abc@xyz.com?subject=Interesting information&body=&#x3C;a href=&#x22;w3schools.com&#x22;&#x3E;Free Web Building Tutorials!&#x3C;/a&#x3E;
```

Basically, Html encode the url.

Comment: Doesn't work.  If i do something like :onclick="javascript:window.location='mailto:?subject=Interesting information&body=I thought you might find this information interesting: ' <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Free Web Building Tutorials!</a>"

Comment: Updated the answer